# Invalid property value on foreignObject (FIREFOX)

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I have a foreignObject in my page, with position defined by `X`and `Y` values.

```
 <foreignObject style="X:883;Y:540;">
      <input type="checkbox">
 </foreignObject>
```

When I open it in Chrome, it works fine but when I open my page on Firefox the position does not work. If I inspect the element, I see a warning : `Invalid property value` on `X`and `Y`.

Any idea where it's coming from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your code, the documentation says that it should be used like:

```
 <foreignObject x="883" y="540">
  <input type="checkbox">
 </foreignObject>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

the style attribute is existent, but is used for other cases. 
The y and x are own attributes and must be used as well.